# Dynamically resize divs on image according browser windows size

Tags: html, css, dynamic, browser

On my beta page [betapage_h2o](http://www.h2o-info.com/betapage/home/teilanlage-1/) you can see the result, what I have so far.

It works great with resolution 1920x1080, but it should work with other resolutions too, from 1366x768 and greater.

If I resize the browser window, the image gets smaller, but the divs like #water_detail and #water_procent should also get resized and stay within the tank graphic.

So far, I got an image with size 1900x700 positioned in the content, and over that I want to place some divs with dynamically values and animations, to describe the graphic in detail.

Well, for now the divs with the values are placed with fixed px values (margin etc.), but what would be the right way?

Perhaps can someone give me an advice or the right way to achieve this.

Ty in advance

Comment: have a google for media queries